# Vue - v-for attaching computed props

Tags: object, vue.js, methods, vuejs2, v-for

I am passing some tasks into my v-form

```
tasks: [
        {
          title: 'title1', 
          description: 'task 1 description',
          isComplete: function1()
        },
        {
          title: 'title2',
          description: 'this is another description',
          isComplete: function1()
        } 
      ]
    };
```

Task 1 and 2 have different functions to test if they are completed. Can I pass them in via the object?

Comment: _"Can I pass them in via the object?"_ <- could you please explain what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I was trying to use computed props but this worked where task1Complete() and task2Complete() are regular methods.

```
tasks: [
        {
          title: 'title1', 
          description: 'task 1 description',
          complete: this.task1Complete()
        },
        {
          title: 'title2',
          description: 'this is another description',
          complete: this.task2Complete()
        } 
      ]
    };
```

The v-for

```
  <div
      v-for="(task, index) in tasks"
      :key="index"
      :class="{'is-complete': task.complete}"
    >
```